# Visual Studio- Task List is empty

Tags: c++, task

I don't know how it is happened, but suddenly my Task list is empty.

[image]

I checked `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> view`,
but I did not find anything wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must enable following option:

[image]

Also only displays for current open document.

Comment: Thank you,

As I showed at the picture at my question: The order "Enumerate Comment Tasks" is "True" and although I do not see nothing at my Task List.  

 I do not understnad your advice "displays for current open document". my cpp file is open and I can see him at "Source file" in the "Solution Explorar".

Comment: I've the same problem. Did you ever found a solution?